# I tired to implement clean architecture, how does clean code and architecture matter?

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture

I'm a self-taught software developer I have worked with several tech companies for more than 6 years.
Currently, I work as a senior android developer in a company which I'm responsible for the mobile development department, I have delivered apps for customers that my managers are satisfied with.
I see myself as a senior and highly skilled as my co-workers and managers say.
Recently I started looking for new opportunities in bigger companies I had many interviews and always pass screening, cultural and behavioural interviews, but I got rejected many times in coding challenges because of the following:
1- No clean architecture.
2- There are logics in the UI

The first rejection I read a lot about clean code and architecture and tried to implement what I learned in the next interviews I got, but unfortunately, I keep getting the same feedback.
Maybe the resources I read are not good enough for nowadays approach.
Any advice to improve myself would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Start by reading Clean Code and Clean Architecture books written by Robert Martin.

Comment: Yeah, I started reading it. Thanks for your reply